# How to create and display Fragments from inside an Android Library?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I'm relatively new to Android / Kotlin.

I wonder how Android libraries like AdMob manage to create and show a View (especially an Intersitial Ad) from inside a library without any layout preparation of the integrating app. I assume this View is some sort of Fragment.

Sample code to show an intersitial ad from [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial):

I think it somehow has to do with the Activity passed as a parameter in the show method.

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
  mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
} else {
  Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
}
```

This [Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create) states, that to add a fragment programmatically, "the layout should include a FragmentContainerView". Additionally in the sample code from the same guide the id of said FragmentContainerView is used to add the fragment. This id is not known inside the library.

```
class ExampleActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.example_activity) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add<ExampleFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How does such a library achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve it.

A working demo can be found here:  https://github.com/eat-your-broccoli/add-fragment-from-library-demo

Library:

```
class FragmentManager {
    companion object {
        fun showFragment(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
(activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
                activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, DemoFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()
            }
        }
    }
}

class DemoFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var btnBack: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false)

        // enable back button
        btnBack = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back)
        btnBack.setOnClickListener {
            this.activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack()
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

And in my activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var btnSwitch: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnSwitch = findViewById(R.id.btn_switch)
        btnSwitch.setOnClickListener {
            FragmentManager.showFragment(this)
        }
    }
}
```

A problem I had was that using `R.id.content` instead of `android.R.id.content` caused an execption and crashed the app.

Comment: Thank you. It took me a day!

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how Android libraries like AdMob manage to create and show a View (especially an Intersitial Ad) from inside a library without any layout preparation of the integrating app.

What "layout preparations" would the integrating app need to do? Given an Activity, which you pass to the method, any code can use `Activity.startActivity` to launch it's own Activity which can be styled / themed in any way with any layout the library chooses (such as showing an interstitial ad).

> I assume this View is some sort of Fragment.

Why would you assume that? It could be a Fragment, but it would be contained within an Activity, which could be launched as I've indicated above.

> This Guide states, that to add a fragment programmatically, "the layout should include a FragmentContainerView". Additionally in the sample code from the same guide the id of said FragmentContainerView is used to add the fragment. This id is not known inside the library.

Right. But that again assumes tha the library is only using a Fragment and trying to shove it into your heirarchy. That's highly unlikely. It's more likely starting a brand new Activity that it knows about and has full control over.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I thought all activities have to be declared in the mainfest, which is something I'd like to avoid. Does such an activity have to be declared?

Comment: It does - the library would declare it in its own manifest and it would get merged into yours. You can review the final output of your manifest and confirm this is the case: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts